# The template parameter of my partial template specialization is not deducible

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, type-traits, c++17

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
template<class E>
class vector_expression {};

template<class Tuple>
class vector
    : public vector_expression<vector<Tuple>>
{
public:
    using value_type = typename Tuple::value_type;
};

template<typename T>
using dynamic_vector = vector<std::vector<T>>;

namespace detail
{
    template<class E>
    constexpr bool is_vector_expression_v = std::is_base_of_v<vector_expression<std::decay_t<E>>, std::decay_t<E>>;

    template<class E>
    struct value_type { using type = std::decay_t<E>; };
    template<class E>
    struct value_type<vector_expression<std::decay_t<E>>> { using type = typename std::decay_t<E>::value_type; };
    template<class E>
    using value_type_t = typename value_type<E>::type;
}


int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<detail::value_type_t<dynamic_vector<double>>, double>::value, "not the same");   
    return 0;
}
```

I want `value_type_t<E>` to be the `value_type` specified in `E` whenever `E` is a `vector_expression`. The code above is not working, cause the template parameter `E` is not deducible in the partial specialization of `value_type`. How can I make the code work?

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5cb60e921f3d3ad)

Comment: Like [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35a7e10935ac63a0) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::decay_t<E>` is not deducible as it is in fact `std::decay<E>::type` (and indeed, several `E` can lead to same type in your specific case).

A second fix is needed to pass your `static_assert`:

As `dynamic_vector<double>` is not `vector_expression` but inherit from it, your specialization doesn't match. You may use SFINAE to fix that:

```
template<class E, typename Enabler = void>
struct value_type { using type = std::decay_t<E>; };

template<class E>
struct value_type<E, std::enable_if_t<is_vector_expression_v<E>>> {
    using type = typename std::decay_t<typename E::type>::value_type;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4f4e7538f1e66ef)

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that your partial specialization is non-deducible. That's an easier fix, you can just drop the `std::decay_t`:

```
template<class E>
struct value_type<vector_expression<E>> { using type = typename E::value_type; };
```

However, now you have the bigger problem in that this does not do what you want it to do. `dynamic_vector<double>` is not a `vector_expression<E>` for any `E`. It *inherits* from `vector_expression<vector<std::vector<T>>>`, but that won't help for the purposes of this match. So the above fix will compile, but you'd still match the primary template - giving you the wrong `value_type`.

What you probably want is to specialize on the presence of `value_type` as a typedef. That is:

```
template <class... > using void_t = void;
template <class T> struct tag_t { using type = T; }; // courtesy of Yakk

template<class E, class=void>
struct value_type : tag_t<std::decay_t<E>> { };

template<class E>
struct value_type<E, void_t<typename std::decay_t<E>::value_type>> 
: tag_t<typename std::decay_t<E>::value_type> { };
```

And now your `static_assert` passes.